# What is a modern headless testing option for single page apps?

Tags: angular, phantomjs, headless-browser

I recently started an Angular 2 application.  I went to phantomjs (latest version, 2.1) for [headless testing](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2013), and it was blowing up on 'const' keyword.
A [little research](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) led me to believe that phantomjs is way behind for implementing es6.

- Am I reading this right?
- Does anyone know if they're on the verge of catching up is my above assumption is right?
- Is there another option?

Comment: There are some libraries that use xvfb to run chrome or firefox headlessly

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/). It was created with Angular in mind.